# ¿Como buscar un pdf en un directorio y luego visualizarlo en una nueva pestaña?

Tags: php, descarga

tengo 100 archivos pdfs cargados en mi hosting, en un directorio(carpeta), necesito llamarlos por búsqueda (frontend) y luego me muestre url del que cumpla con la busqueda (frontend) para posteriormente ser visualizado en el mismo navegador en un pestaña nueva (por medio de un boton).

Comment: Hola, tu código no muestra algo de avance para poder lograr el cometido. No creo que necesites la intervención de php salvo cuando los tienes que buscar y regresarlos al front-end para después filtrarlos.

Comment: dices traerlos con php luego filtrarlos con javascript, no seria doble trabajo?, ahora estoy implementando la función glob() para tratar rutas, es precisamente lo que necesito

Answer (score 0):

Listo solucionado

```
<?php
//aca llamo desde el fomulario el dato a buscar en mis ficheros
$cc=$_POST['cedula'];
//se crea la ruta a buscar
$nombre_fichero = './archivos/'.$_POST['cedula'].'.pdf';
//se comprueba que mi ruta exista (busqueda)
if (file_exists($nombre_fichero)) {
    echo "Documento $cc Disponible para ";       
    ?>
<a href="<?php echo $nombre_fichero; ?>">Descargar</a>
//genero el link y listo :)            
<?php    
} else {
//si no existe el fichero
    echo "La Cédula  $cc no existe";
}
?>
```